# Yet a doubt on integration inside a function

Tags: calculus

I'm in another trouble.

Let $f(x) = x^3 - 3x + \dfrac{8}{3}\int_0^1{f(x)}\mathrm{d}x$. Find both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$.

As at this time I have one single variable $a$ to denote $a = \int_0^1{f(x)}\mathrm{d}x$, I don't know how to isolate it to resolve. How can I solve this ?

Comment: $$\int_0^1 \left(x^3-3x+\frac{8a}{3} \right) dx = a.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=n
$$
$$
f(x)=x^3-3x-\frac{8}{3}n
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}(x^3-3x-\frac{8}{3}n)dx
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{1}(x^3-3x-\frac{8}{3}n)dx=n
$$
$$
\frac{1}{4}-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{8}{3}n=n
$$

$$
n=-\frac{15}{44}
$$

$$
f(x)=x^3-3x+\frac{10}{11}
$$

Comment: please do correct your answer! because $f(x) = x^3 - 3x + \frac{8}3 n$, and hence $n = \frac3{4}$ (or so it seems.)

Comment: I think there's a typo in the function definition.